# bind9 TLD response uppercase?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm running bind9 on a server with recursion on for my home IP to experiment with running my own resolver.

It is working quite well most of the time, but occasionally this command:

```
nslookup -querytype=SRV _xmpp-client._tcp.sette.ca
```

Will return:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
_xmpp-client._tcp.sette.CA  service = 5 0 5222 singpolyma.net.
```

instead of the normal answer:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
_xmpp-client._tcp.sette.ca  service = 5 0 5222 singpolyma.net.
```

This causes resolution with some of my client applications to fail.  While DNS should be case-insensitive (I think?) and so maybe this is a bug in the applications I'm using, it still seems strange that occasionally my server would choose a different case to return.  Google DNS and my ISP DNS never seem to do this, and most of the time neither does my server.

Has anyone seen something like this before?  What could cause bind9 to return a different case than I used in the query?

Answer (score 1):

Names in DNS are case insensitive, meaning that `_xmpp-client._tcp.sette.ca.`, `_xmpp-client._tcp.sette.CA.`, `_xMpP-cLiEnT._tCp.SeTtE.cA.`, etc are all considered equal, so it's not actually incorrect per se.

One possible reason why this could occur (not clear from `nslookup`'s limited output), is as a result of [message compression](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4.1.4), where some other name included in the response was in uppercase and its uppercase `CA` was re-used as part of your name.

Comment: I know it's not incorrect per-se, but for some reason it breaks some programs on my network when it happens.  Restarting my bind server "fixes" it and the only change in response I can see is that it becomes all lowercase

Comment: " it breaks some programs" Those programs are then buggy and they should be fixed. As for "Restarting my bind server "fixes" it" it is because, aside from name compression as Håkan said (easy to see if you do a network sniffing), changing case is a known trick to mitigate the Kaminsky attack, it is called the 0x20 trick. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-vixie-dnsext-dns0x20-00 or http://courses.isi.jhu.edu/netsec/papers/increased_dns_resistance.pdf or details from Dan Kaminsky himself at https://dankaminsky.com/2008/08/29/towards-the-next-dns-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this too, but it causes no issues with any apps for me.  I suspect it is something tied to DNSSEC.  I noticed this once I upgraded bind9 to a version that required DNSSEC.  I suspect there is a failure with DNSSEC, but I have not found it yet.  My issue is with .ORG goes uppercase and can randomly stay there until the .ORG servers expire.  It maybe a possible packet loss when it is trying to verify the .ORG TLD.